# Conditional Styling in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have this ImageBackground tag in my React-Native App.

```
const{height,width} = Dimensions.get('window);
const navHeight = ExtraDimensions.get('SOFT_MENU_BAR_HEIGHT');

render(){
 return(
  <ImageBackground source={Images.bg} style={{width=width+48,height=height}}>
     //content
  </ImageBackground>
 );
}
```

The number 48 is the height of the default Android navigation bar (the one contains BACK button). The `navHeight` is to detect the height of navigation bar on the device (refer here:https://github.com/Sunhat/react-native-extra-dimensions-android).

Since there are now devices with no navigation bar, i want to make a conditional styling in the ImageBackground style to take `style={styles.bg1}` when there is a value of `navHeight` and take `style={styles.bg2}` when there is no `navHeight` value.
May i know where and how should i implement the styling? thanks

My current wrong way of doing it is

```
<ImageBackground source={Images.bg} style={navHeight=0 ? styles.bg1 : styles.bg2}>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a syntatical error, for comparison you have to use `==`.

Try this,

```
<ImageBackground source={Images.bg} style={ (navHeight==0) ? styles.bg1 : styles.bg2}>
```

Moreover, i would recommend you using `Image` tag and append a child component to it by using `position="absolute"`. Because some styling props like `borderRadius` don't work in the case of `ImageBackground` tag.

I hope this helps you !

Comment: Thanks. It works. However i made a silly mistake in declaring const to a number. It should be var navHeight instead.